# Could i add fragment to list_item.xml to use inside Recycle View

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

I need to add fragment to recyclerView item is there any way ?
I tried to set the adapter for the recyclerview but i got the blew error 
i don't know if it possible to do such that or i need to add the fragment inside the code using getFragmentManager

this is my list_item.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/mFragment"
        android:name="com.ma.myFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_layout" />


</LinearLayout>
```

here my oncreateholder method

```
@Override
public ListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    context = parent.getContext();
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,true);

    return new ViewHolder(view);
}
```

This is the Error

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #3: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:770)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude(LayoutInflater.java:904)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
at testvideo.rubits.com.testvideo.ListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:36)
at com.ma.ListAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(ListAdapter.java:19)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6367)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5555)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5440)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5436)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2224)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1551)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1511)
at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:595)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3583)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3312)
at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:3844)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1691)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1467)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:573)
at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:508)
at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16804)
at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5328)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2324)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2037)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1196)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6675)
at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.di
```

Comment: Try replacing this  :: View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);

Comment: even if you could find a working solution i think this is not a good approach. There is a reason to act like this?

Comment: @zephyr same problem

Answer (score 0):

What you want will not work out.
A RecyclerView is not meant to have fragments in its child views. The views inside a recycler view will be recycled but you can not simply recycle fragments.

You could try to dynamically replace the fragments inside the child views using the fragment manager in onBindViewHolder. But even if it works it wouldn't be a good solution.

Why do you need to use fragments in a recycler view at all?

Comment: a created a video player fragment and i need to play videos inside a list

Comment: Then maybe you should use a video view instead of a video fragment.

Comment: yes i just converted the video fragment to a custom view but i lost the ability to detect onPause,onResume,ondestroy of the video fragment now i have to call the same functions outside the video view